# Unresolved reference in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class, who implement ArrayAdapter.
The problem, is that I need to reference an ImageView and TextView, whose id is imageViewIcon and textViewName, but when I use findViewById, I get the error Unresolved Reference

This is class, who implement the Adapter and where I get the error

```
class DrawerItemCustomAdapter(context: Context, var resource: Int, objects: Array<DataModel>): ArrayAdapter<DataModel>(
    context,
    resource,
    objects
) {
    var mContext: Context? = context
    var layoutResourceId = resource
    var data: Array<DataModel>? = objects
    public override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

      //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        var listItem = convertView!!

        val inflater = (mContext as Activity).layoutInflater
        listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false)

        val imageViewIcon = listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon) as ImageView
        val textViewName = listItem.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewName) as TextView

        val (icon, name) = data!![position]


        imageViewIcon.setImageResource(icon)
        textViewName.text = name

        return listItem

    }
}
```

This is list_view_item_row.xml, where the TextView And ImageView is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the activity, where I use the Adapter

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.new_main)


        var drawerItem = arrayOf<DataModel>(DataModel(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "Connect"))
    
        val adapter:DrawerItemCustomAdapter= DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem )}
```

Comment: Where exactly you are getting `Unresolved Reference` ? can you add the line and error with question .

Comment: It's in DrawerItemCustomAdapter, getView. val imageViewIcon = listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon) as ImageView

Comment: It should not give `Unresolved Reference` . Just invalidate cache and restart the IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalidate"?

Comment: In `File` menu there should be an option `invalidate cache and restart`.

Comment: I did that, but the error is still there